# Collecting unique records from an array of models with has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an `AnswerSheet` that `has_many :answers`, and each `Answer belongs_to :question`.

I do something like `@answer_sheet.answers.where(is_correct: false).map(&:question)` to get all the incorrectly answered questions.

`Question has_many :question_skills` and `has_many :skills, through: :question_skills`, and I want to get all the unique skills for that set of questions.

I had tried `.map(&:skills)` on the result of the above, but that gives me an array of `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`, which I think is not quite what I want.

This also seems like a performance nightmare.

If you have suggestions on how to improve this question title, I'd be more than happy to generalize the question.

Comment: `Question has_many :question_skills`, then how `map(&:skills)`, not `map(&:question_skills)` ? I am bit confused about it..

Comment: I failed to mention there's a `has_many :skills, through: :question_skills`. Will edit.

Comment: You can do `questions.map { |question| questions.skills.to_a }.uniq`.. But I don't know if it is efficient or not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use associations to answer all these questions (pun intended). First,  add some new associations for correct/incorrect answers.

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end

class AnswerSheet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers

  has_many :incorrect_answers, -> { where is_correct: false }, class_name: 'Answer'
  has_many :incorrectly_answered_questions, class_name: 'Question', through: :incorrect_answers, source: :question

  has_many :correct_answers, -> { where is_correct: true }, class_name: 'Answer'
  has_many :correctly_answered_questions, class_name: 'Question', through: :correct_answers, source: :question

  has_many :skills_for_correct_answers, class_name: 'Skill', through: :correctly_answered_questions, source: :skills
  has_many :skills_for_incorrect_answers, class_name: 'Skill', through: :incorrectly_answered_questions, source: :skills
end
```

Now you can get at the records more directly:

```
# get all incorrect answers
answer_sheet.incorrect_answers

# get all incorrectly answered questions
answer_sheet.incorrectly_answered_questions

# get all correctly answered questions
answer_sheet.correctly_answered_questions
```

Your second question about how to find the unique skills can be done by calling uniq on the results

```
answer_sheet.skills_for_incorrect_answers.uniq
```

Comment: I was looking for all the unique skills on the set of questions returned by `.incorrectly_answered_questions`.

Comment: @JoshSmith, I updated my answer with new associations that will retrieve the skills.

Answer (score 0):

It's normally best to let the DB formulate the answer from a single query.  For the first query, this would be something like:

```
Question.joins(:answer_sheets, :answers).where(
  'answer_sheets.id = ? and not answers.is_correct', @answer_sheet.id)
```

and with this as a pattern, for the second:

```
Skill.joins(:questions, :answer_sheets, :answers).select('skills.id,skills.text').
  where('answer_sheets.id = ? and not answers.is_correct', @answer_sheet.id).
  distinct
```

We need the `select` to allow `distinct` to work. Adjust fields as needed.

Of course this is untested, but it ought to be close.